# Vue.js: Using propsData in a jasmine test

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using browserify and vue.js and have a basic Jasmine test working - looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Cast from '../../../frontend/components/Cast.vue'

describe('Cast.vue', () => {
  it('should render correct contents', () => {
    const vm = new Vue({
      data: { cast: {name: 'testName'} },
      template: '<div><cast :cast="cast"></cast></div>',
      components: { Cast }
    }).$mount()
    expect(vm.$el.querySelector('tr td').textContent).toBe('testName')
  })
})
```

The test passes fine - I setup data in the outer vm, and that is then passed through to the props in the Cast component. However, there is the idea of `propsData` which I think will give me a cleaner way to initialize my component for testing, but I couldn't work out how to do it. Any help would be most appreciated :)

In case it helps, my component looks like this:

```
<template>
  <tr>
    <td>{{ cast.name }}</td>
  </tr>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  props: {
    cast: Object
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: i don't really get your point, any reference of what are you looking for?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. https://forum.vuejs.org/topic/3869/unit-testing-how-to-create-mocks-for-props/6 might give more context. I think I'm probably misunderstanding how to initialize a component in a test properly. In the above I'm creating a VM around the component I'm interested in testing (Cast) and then passing data to the VM which then initializes the Cast itself. What I'd like to do, I think, is just create an instance of the Cast itself somehow. But I'm not sure this is possible.   http://vuejs.org/api/#propsData is the propsData option.

Comment: If i get well your question, you want to add custom data to the object that is being passed as prop so you can test if the component recieves the prop correctly, is it right?

Comment: I want to see how to use `propsData` in a test. If it's possible just instantiating a Cast component directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick example on how to unit test a Vue component with `propsData`

Your example still failed for me, but I think you're supposed to provide the `el` at instantiation instead of when defining the component like in your example. The following passed for me!

```
it('works with propsData', () => {
  var mount = document.createElement('div');
  var Comp = Vue.extend({
    props: ['msg'],
    template: '<div>{{ msg }}</div>'
  });

  var vm = new Comp({
    el: mount,
    propsData: {
      msg: 'hello',
    },
  });

  expect(vm.msg).toEqual('hello');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In the event I used @broox's post to point me in the right direction. The trick was extending Vue in the `.vue` file.

```
<template>
  <tr>
    <td>{{ cast.name }}</td>
  </tr>
</template>

<script>

    import Vue from 'vue'

    export default Vue.extend({
      props....
    )}

</script>
```

and then in the test, creating the div element and passing that in as the `el` param with the propsData. After that - all good!

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Cast from '../../../frontend/components/Cast.vue'

describe('Cast.vue', () => {
  it('should render name of cast correctly', () => {
    var mount = document.createElement('div');
    const vm = new Cast({
      el: mount,
      propsData: { cast: {name: 'testName'} },
    })
    expect(vm.$el.querySelector('tr td').textContent.trim()).toBe('testName')
  });
```

I'll leave @broox's answer as the accepted one, but perhaps this answer will help anyone using vueify and testing components.